# Get Auth0 Management token using rest template java

Tags: java, web-services, auth0

Is there any way to get auth0 management token token using rest template?

Comment: Jai, can you explain a little what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Getting an Auth0 Management token just requires crafting an https request with the right params

Comment: I want management token in my code using rest, using that token i will do some business for my application

Comment: So are you asking whether you can get a Management Token, or whether you can send a token with a REST request?

Comment: Hi Jai, be grateful if you would mark the answer correct as it addresses your question. if you still have any probs, then leave comments.

Comment: Using java i need to get the management token with all scope. Your answer used to get access token only not management api token.

Answer (score 3):

Left you comments as unclear precisely what you are asking. But in summary, getting an Auth0 Management Token should be possible with any Java library that handles HTTP request / response.

Quick example of how this might look with say HttpClient library:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{\n\t\"client_id\":\"{{CLIENT ID}}\",\n\t\"client_secret\":\"{{CLIENT SECRET}}\",\n\t\"audience\":\"https://{{TENANT}}.auth0.com/api/v2/\",\n\t\"grant_type\":\"client_credentials\"\n\t\n}");
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("https://{{TENANT}}.auth0.com/oauth/token")
  .post(body)
  .addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
  .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Here is a screenshot of the resultant Token in [jwt.io](https://jwt.io):

[image]

Comment: Guess this is for getting access token. i want Auth0 management api token.see this link https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2/tokens

Comment: The above is for getting an Auth0 Management API v2 token

Comment: Notice the audience param `https://{{TENANT}}.auth0.com/api/v2/` - that tells you which API it is intended for.

Comment: i have tried, my guess was correct- above code is to get the access token only. i want management token, that token includes all the scopes that are granted to the API Explorer Client. using this token we can do crud operation via in our code

Comment: Jai - the above works for receiving a JWT Managment API access token with defined scopes you assigned to it. Disclaimer: am intimately familiar with the Auth0 offering...  shall add a screenshot to help your understanding.

Comment: i want do get the token using java. Is there any way ?? can i have some code examples? (Note: i don't want access token, i wanna get Management token that includes scope and all)